# Master thesis topic - mod_security

Tags: security

Are there any research to be done that could use mod_security?

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can get a masters degree for something like this?  Extraordinary.

Comment: security.stackexchange.com may be a good place to ask this.

Comment: @duffymo as a self-taught, yeah, this blows my mind too. I thought a thesis was intended to expand the science, not summarize it.

Comment: Thanks, I posted to security.stackexchange.com Well it's not my master thesis subject yet. I'm trying to figure out if and how can it be used in a master thesis, okay?

Comment: @user257493 - no, doctoral dissertations expand science, not masters thesis.  A masters thesis can be a summary, but I believe this topic is done enough where it hardly seems worthy to me.

Answer (score 4):

There's some sentiment out there that tools like `mod_security` don't *actually* increase security at all.  Sure, they do "block" common vectors, so they are not useless.  But the thing is, the only way to secure code is to make the code secure.  Everything else is just a band-aid.  That's not to say they are not useful as an extra line of defense.  The best defense is multi-layered.  But my point is that mod_security is not *securing* any websites.  It's just plugging common holes (which are more than likely not present)...  There's a fine line in there, but it's a line that has to be drawn...

As far as how to make it more *research-like*, I would simply do your homework.  Go out and look at real world attacks and attack vectors.  Look at the common themes.  If you don't understand how the attacks are happening in the first place, how can you possibly hope to build a tool or create rules to defend against them?!?!?

But that's just my $0.02...